# margins right and left are not equal

Tags: fonts, header-footer, margins, fontspec

Please look at my MWE. I would expect odd and even side margins being the same but they are not. What I am doing that is wrong? I have tried all solutions that were suggested, but they haven't worked.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,A4, english]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\footskip}{\paperheight
  -(1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight)
  -0.75in}

\pagestyle{plain} 
%Arial
\usepackage{arial}                           % load package which provides the font
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ua1}               % set default serif font as Arial
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}             % set default serif font as Arial
%margin
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\textwidth 17.5cm
\textheight 27cm
\evensidemargin \oddsidemargin

\setlength\topmargin{(\paperheight-\textheight
-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip)/2 - 1in}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}

\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%STARTHERE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\layout



\end{document}
```

Comment: Margins are asymmetric in twosided documents. This will make sure that the double margin in the middle will be the same size (modulo the space for binding) as the single margins on the outer edges.

Comment: I know, but it is not the case for me. That is why I asked

Comment: It seems to work fine if I remove all your settings in which you manually overwrite the geometry package

Comment: What layout do you try to achieve? I'm sure it will be easier to tell the geometry package what to do than doing it manually.

Comment: I am writing a research plan that should be at most 4 pages. That is why I keep changing the margin.

Comment: ... better use the options of the geometry package

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail? I am not an expert

Comment: Remove all your manual changes and try e.g. `\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=1cm]{geometry}` See the geometry package documentation for a full list of available options.

Comment: Oh! That is great! Thanks!

Comment: You could just use `oneside` to eliminate the difference, but it sounds as if you want to change the margins anyway.  (Unless you need distinct headers/footers for odd/even pages.)